# Send a frontend Form by email

Tags: forms, email, vuejs2, laravel-7

I'm using Vue 2 and Laravel 7 to build a website...in my client side I put a Contact form that i'd like to send by email (a Vue component). I found tons of ways to do it with Laraval using blade but I can't use blade in a Vue project and I have to take the values from Vue.
Can someone explain me the steps to do it?
I found some easy ways like emailjs but I have the send even some checkboxes values and I can't do it with that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you can just simply create an email template view in the laravel end
> and when on the view project you are submitting the form values you
> put those values in that email template and send it though check this
> for reference [doc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_sending_email.htm)